# Remove localstorage object before navigating to other link in angular 8

Tags: angular, redirect, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I am using angular 8 and implementing login and logout functionality. To achieve that I am using localstorage to remember user data. After Login I am setting data in localStorage and while logging user out I am removing localstorage data Like.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../../api.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header-manual',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  localStorageObject = {};
  constructor( private router: Router , private api: ApiService) { }

  handleLogout(flag){
    if(!flag)           
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);

    let access_token = this.localStorageObject && this.localStorageObject['token'];
    if(access_token){
      this.api.postAPI('LogoutAPI' , {"access_token" : access_token}).subscribe(data => { 
        localStorage.removeItem('users');
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        } ,30)
      })
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.localStorageObject = (localStorage.getItem('users')) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')) : "";
    if(!this.localStorageObject || !this.localStorageObject['token']){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
      } ,30)
    }
  }

}
```

Issue : It's navigating but not rendering login component instead rendering same component through router-outlet.
If I remove localstorage.removeItem(....) then it's working fine but my requirement is to remove localstorage object before redirecting.

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi I have added as edit

Comment: are you getting any error on `console` at `logout` ?

Comment: Please, add also the logic in the `login` component

Comment: in your code are some type errors. You init your localStorageObject as empty object. In ngInit you are trying to create it from locale storage otherwise init it with an emtpy string. Please give this boy a type and init it with null always ... You should have an model Class User.